# Poincaré's Lemma in the space of tempered distributions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

It is well known that if $f\in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^3)$ and $\textbf{curl} f= 0$ then there exists a  $u\in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^3)$ such that $\nabla u = f$.

**Question.** Does the same result still hold with $f\in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^3)$ and $u\in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^3)$?

Comment: $S'$ is closed under the Fourier transform.

Comment: Since $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^3) \subset \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R}^3)$ there exists $u \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R})$ such that $\nabla u = f$. The question is therefore whether $u \in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^3,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @reuns also $\mathcal{S}$ is closed under Fourier transform.

Comment: What does the proof look like for ordinary distributions?

Comment: Th. VI, p. 59 in ["Schwartz, Laurent, Théorie des distributions. Vol. 2. Paris: Hermann, 1959"]). You can find an English proof in Proposition 4.3.9, page 334 of ["Horváth, John. Topological vector spaces and distributions. Courier Corporation, 2012"]

Comment: Google Books has Horváth's book, but page 334 is sadly not shown. I guess that you have studied the proof and found something in it that is not valid for a tempered distribution.

Comment: I found a paper about Stokes' formula on the space of tempered distributions:
https://www.math.lsu.edu/cosa/8-3-06[439].pdf

Comment: @md2perpe the above link is now a redirect to the COSA journal homepage. This is the DOI number:10.31390/cosa.8.3.06 (and currently working link: https://digitalcommons.lsu.edu/cosa/vol8/iss3/6/)

Answer (score 1):

As **reuns** commented, $\mathcal S'$ is closed under Fourier transforms.

Using $\hat f(k) = \int_{\mathbb R^3} f(x) \, e^{-i k \cdot x} \, dx$ the Fourier transform of $\nabla \times f(x) = 0$ becomes $ik \times \hat f(k) = 0$. Thus $\hat f(k)$ is parallel to $ik$ for all $k \in \mathbb R^3,$ i.e. there is a function $\hat u \in \mathcal S'(\mathbb R^3, \mathbb R)$ such that $\hat f(k) = ik \, \hat u(k).$ An inverse Fourier transform then gives $f(x) = \nabla u(x).$

Comment: Would be nice :-) If you write down explicitly what you wrote you continuously go out from the test space $\mathcal{S}$.

Comment: @Josh, I'm not even working inside $\mathcal S$. I'm working in $\mathcal S'$. Do I go outside of that?

Comment: For example, the condition $ik \times \hat f(k) = 0$ reads as $\langle f,i k \times \hat \phi(k)\rangle= 0$ for every $ \hat \phi \in \mathcal{S}$. And if your saying that $\hat f(k)$ and $ik$ are parallel comes from projecting  $\hat \phi(k)$ along $i k$ and along the orthogonal space to $i k$ than these two terms not necessarily are still in $\mathcal{S}$ although their sum is in  $\mathcal{S}$. In other terms, you seem too easy in deducing not only that the two distributions are parallel, but also that the projection of $\hat f$ on $i k$ is in $\mathcal S'(\mathbb R^3, \mathbb R)$.

Comment: This seems right in principle. But it needs some fixing: $\hat f$ is not a function, so saying anything about $\hat f(k)$ is meaningless.